# Циклические зависимости при определении класса

Tags: java

При инициализации класса могут возникать [deadlock'и](https://habrahabr.ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/255067/).

Например, есть следующий код

```
class A {
  static final B b = new B();
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Это потенциально проблемное место. Есть ли какие то решения для такого кода, позволяющие избежать данную ситуацию?

UDP:

Напишу подробнее.

Есть реализация неизменяемого списка.

```
abstract class List<T>{
   private static final List<Object> EMPTY = new Empty<>();

   private remove(int index){
       if(index<0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index must be more zero");
       return  innerRemove(index);
   }   
   protected abstract List<T> innerRemove(int index);


   public static List<T> create(){
        return EMPTY;
   } 
}

class Empty<T> extends List<T>{
   protected List<T> innerRemove(int index){return this}
}
```

Comment: А что можно менять в приведённом коде и как он должен в итоге работать? Надо как-то более лучше, что ли, сформмулировать желаемый результат

Comment: Неверное, можно просто весь функционал А вынести в интерфейс и имплементировать в обоих классах его.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с интерфейсами это понятно, но не хочется избавляться от наследования, т.к. возникает дублирование кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно перенести поле `EMPTY` в класс `Empty` с соответствующей сменой видимости (как это и [сделано](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/f3099c7e01df0f240615eea996ec0c973a47aa11) в Guava).

Тогда класс `Empty` будет инициализирован либо при вызове `List.create()` (класс `List` в этот момент уже загружен), либо сам по себе (что может вызвать загрузку `List`, но т.к. `List` больше не требует `Empty`, дедлок исключен)